# Linked list reversed in groups of K nodes

Tags: c, algorithm, linked-list, reverse, singly-linked-list

Initially, the interviewer asked the question to reverse the linked list which I solved easily.
Now he said to reverse the list in groups of K nodes.

for example, if the list is `[1,2,3,4,5,6]` and `K=4` then `o/p = [4,3,2,1,5,6].`. So I have modified the existing solution to achieve it but still, it gives the output of the whole list reversed (`i.e [6,5,4,3,2,1]`). see the below program. It might be some minor change needed but I couldn't figure out it. Can anyone help where is issue?

```
ListNode *reverseKGroup(ListNode *head, int k) 
{
    if (k == 0 || k == 1)
        return head;

    if (head == NULL)
        return NULL;

    int counter = 0;
    ListNode *fastPtr = head;
    ListNode *currentPtr = head;
    ListNode *nextPtr = NULL;
    ListNode *prevPtr = NULL;
        
    while (fastPtr)
    {
        counter++;

        //one chain formed from list, reverse it
        if (counter == k)
        {
            fastPtr = fastPtr->next;
            
            while (counter)
            {
                nextPtr = currentPtr->next;
                currentPtr->next = prevPtr;
                prevPtr = currentPtr;
                currentPtr = nextPtr;
                counter--;
            }

            //last node
            if (currentPtr->next == NULL)
            {
                currentPtr->next = prevPtr;
                prevPtr = currentPtr;
                break;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            fastPtr = fastPtr->next;
        }
    }
    
    return prevPtr;
}
```

Comment: Have you tried to *debug* your program? Or tried to use pen and paper to draw and redraw the list and the operations you perform on the list?

Comment: "Now he said to reverse the list in group of K nodes. for example, if the list is [1,2,3,4,5,6] and K=4 then o/p = [4,3,2,1,5,6]." So he wants you to reverse the first K nodes, and leave the next nodes in order? "in groups of K nodes" sounds like [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12] would become [9,10,11,12,6,7,8,9,1,2,3,4].

Comment: To me it's unclear what you want. Do you simply want to reverse the first k elements?

Comment: @4386427 for each group of K elements, he wants to reverse the group, if the last group has less than K elements he will not reverse it.

Comment: @user2520119 what did you do exactly to move from reversing the list to reversing it by groups ?

Comment: @Quade suppose the list is `[1,2,3,4,5,6]` and `k=2` then what i did, get the first group to have number of elements =k, which is `[1,2]` reverse that so it will be `[2,1]`, then pick the second chain `[3 4]`, reverse it which will become `[4,3]` and so on..so final o/p will be `[2,1,4,3,6,5]`.

Comment: @4386427 see description here for a proper understanding of the question. https://leetcode.com/problems/reverse-nodes-in-k-group/

Comment: I don't understand how you attempt to reverse the second group. How do you get the K, I don't see them stored anywhere. What I would advise you to remember is you need to link between the groups, so maintain a pointer to the last node in the first reversed group and when you reverse the second, link this node to the new first node in the second group (this is the key difference between the two problems)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your approach is OK, but you do not link the reversed list fragments correctly:

- you can factorize `fastPtr = fastPtr->next;` as it is performed in both branches of the `if` statement.
- the test for the last node is bogus: `if (currentPtr->next == NULL)` will dereference a null pointer if the list length is a multiple of `k`.
- you should instead keep a pointer to the place where to store the head of the reversed list fragment. At the start of the loop this pointer points to the variable `head`, and after each fragment reversal, it should point to the `next` member of the first node of the fragment before reversal, which is the value of `CurrentNode` at the start of the reversing loop.

With these small modifications, your code runs fine.

Note that this question is tricky. If the interviewer requires from you to solve it interactively, they are probably interested in your approach to problem solving. Constructing an effective and elegant solution in less than half an hour would be very good.

Here is the modified version with a testbed:

```c
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct ListNode {
    struct ListNode *next;
    int data;
} ListNode;

ListNode *reverseKGroup(ListNode *head, int k) {
    if (k > 1) {                     // no need to test for `head != NULL`
        int counter = 0;
        ListNode **start = &head;    // place where to store the head of the reversed fragment
        ListNode *currentPtr = head; // pointer to the first node of the fragment
        ListNode *fastPtr = head;    // pointer to the node after the end of the fragment

        while (fastPtr) {
            fastPtr = fastPtr->next;
            counter++;
            if (counter == k) {
                // k nodes between CurrentPtr and fastPtr: reverse the fragment
                ListNode *lastPtr = currentPtr;
                ListNode *prevPtr = fastPtr;
                while (counter) {
                    ListNode *nextPtr = currentPtr->next;
                    currentPtr->next = prevPtr;
                    prevPtr = currentPtr;
                    currentPtr = nextPtr;
                    counter--;
                }
                *start = prevPtr;
                start = &lastPtr->next;
            }
        }
    }
    return head;
}

void printList(const char *prefix, const ListNode *p, const char *suffix) {
    while (p) {
        printf("%s%d", prefix, p->data);
        prefix = ", ";
        p = p->next;
    }
    printf("%s", suffix);
}

ListNode *test(ListNode *list, int k) {
    printf("reverseKGroup(%d): ", k);
    list = reverseKGroup(list, k);
    printList("", list, "\n");
    return reverseKGroup(list, k); // undo k-reversal
}

int main() {
    ListNode a[10], *list = a;
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        a[i].next = i + 1 < 10 ? &a[i + 1] : NULL;
        a[i].data = i + 1;
    }
    for (int k = 0; k <= 11; k++) {
        list = test(list, k);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
reverseKGroup(0): 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10
reverseKGroup(1): 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10
reverseKGroup(2): 2, 1, 4, 3, 6, 5, 8, 7, 10, 9
reverseKGroup(3): 3, 2, 1, 6, 5, 4, 9, 8, 7, 10
reverseKGroup(4): 4, 3, 2, 1, 8, 7, 6, 5, 9, 10
reverseKGroup(5): 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 10, 9, 8, 7, 6
reverseKGroup(6): 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 7, 8, 9, 10
reverseKGroup(7): 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 8, 9, 10
reverseKGroup(8): 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 9, 10
reverseKGroup(9): 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 10
reverseKGroup(10): 10, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1
reverseKGroup(11): 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10
```

Answer (score 1):

*> it gives the output of the whole list reversed ....*

This is because when next time the control enters to this `if` block

```
if(counter == k)
```

the pointer `prevPtr` is still pointing to same nodes in the list where it was pointing in previous iteration while manipulating the list. You need to set the `prevPtr` to `NULL` while reversing a group of `k` nodes. Along with it, you need to take care of the `head` and `tail` of the list explicitly. The `head` of list will be the `k`<sup>th</sup> node of first group of `k` nodes reversed and `tail` of the list will be the first node of last group of `k` nodes when the nodes in the list are multiple of `k` or it will point to the first node of remaining list when the nodes in the list are not in multiple of `k`. The `tail` of the list need to be take care of while reversing every group of `k` nodes.

Roughly modified your code with taking care of above mentioned details:

```
ListNode* reverseKGroup(ListNode* head, int k) 
{
    if(k==0 || k==1)
        return head;

    if(head == NULL)
        return NULL;

    int counter = 0;
    ListNode* fastPtr = head;
    ListNode* currentPtr = head;
    ListNode* nextPtr = NULL;
    ListNode* prevPtr = NULL;
    ListNode* tail = NULL;
    ListNode* currLast = NULL;
    int set_head = 0;
    int set_currLast = 0;
        
    while(fastPtr)
    {
        counter++;

        //one chain formed from list, reveser it
        if(counter == k)
        {
            fastPtr = fastPtr->next;

            prevPtr = NULL;
            set_currLast = 0;
            while(counter)
            {
                nextPtr = currentPtr->next;
                currentPtr->next = prevPtr;

                // when reversing group of k nodes, the first node will be
                // the last when whole group reversed
                if (!set_currLast) 
                {
                   currLast = currentPtr;
                   set_currLast = 1;
                }
                prevPtr = currentPtr;
                currentPtr = nextPtr;
                counter--;
            }

            // Need to set head just once only
            if (!set_head) {
               tail = head;
               head = prevPtr;
               set_head = 1;
            } else {
               // the tail need to set after reversing every k nodes group
               tail->next = prevPtr;
               tail = currLast;
            }
            // For the last group which will be of size less than k
            tail->next = nextPtr;
        }
        else
        {
            fastPtr = fastPtr->next;
        }
    }

    return head;
}
```

You can use recursion to reverse the nodes in group of `k` nodes in a list. The code will look clean and much easier to understand:

```
struct ListNode * revll(struct ListNode *head, int k) {
        struct ListNode * prev = NULL;
        struct ListNode * curr = head;
        struct ListNode * tmp = NULL;
        int count = k;

        tmp = head;
        while (tmp && count) {
                count--;
                tmp = tmp->next;
        }
        if (count != 0) {
                return head;
        }

        while ((curr != NULL) && (count < k)) {
                tmp = curr->next;
                curr->next = prev;
                prev = curr;
                curr = tmp;
                count++;
        }

        if (tmp) {
                head->next = revll(tmp, k);
        }
        return prev;
}
```

Comment: You should warn that the recursive function is not tail-recursive, so it can cause a **stack overflow** on very long lists and small values of `k`.

Answer (score 0):

> Initially, the interviewer asked the question to reverse the linked
> list which I solved easily. Now he said to reverse the list in group
> of K nodes.

For starters never do any test assignment in an interview. Do not allow somebody to manipulate you and your time. Ignore such firms that give test assignments.

As for the task then for example it is not a good idea to use a recursive function because for big lists you can get a stack overflow.

Also it will be much better to introduce one more structure for declaring the list itself.

I can suggest the following solution.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct Node
{
    int data;
    struct Node *next;
};

struct List
{
    struct Node *head;
};

int push_front( struct List *list, int data )
{
    struct Node *new_node = malloc( sizeof( struct Node ) );
    int success = new_node != NULL;
    
    if ( success )
    {
        new_node->data = data;
        new_node->next = list->head;
        list->head = new_node;
    }
    
    return success;
}

void clear( struct List *list )
{
    while ( list->head != NULL )
    {
        struct Node *tmp = list->head;
        list->head = list->head->next;
        free( tmp );
    }
}

FILE * display( const struct List *list, FILE *fp )
{
    for ( const struct Node *current = list->head; current != NULL; current = current->next )
    {
        fprintf( fp, "%d -> ", current->data );
    }
    
    fputs( "null", fp );
    
    return fp;
}

void reverse_n( struct List *list, size_t n )
{
    if ( !( n < 2 ) )
    {
        for( struct Node **first = &list->head, *last = list->head; last != NULL; )
        {
            for ( size_t i = n; --i != 0 && last; )
            {
                last = last->next;
            }
            
            if ( last != NULL )
            {
                struct Node *next = ( *first )->next;
                ( *first )->next = last->next;
                last = *first;

                for ( size_t i = n; --i != 0; )
                {
                    struct Node *tmp = next;
                    next = next->next;
                    tmp->next = *first;
                    *first = tmp;
                }
                
                first = &last->next;
                last  = last->next;
            }
        }
    }
}

int main(void) 
{
    struct List list = { .head = NULL };
    const int N = 10;
    
    for ( size_t i = 2; i < N + 1; i++ )
    {
        for ( int j = N; j != 0; --j )
        {
            push_front( &list, j - 1 );
        }
    
        putc( '\n', display( &list, stdout ) );
    
        reverse_n( &list, i );
    
        putc( '\n', display( &list, stdout ) );
        
        putc( '\n', stdout );
        
        clear( &list );
    }

    return 0;
}
```

The program output is

```
0 -> 1 -> 2 -> 3 -> 4 -> 5 -> 6 -> 7 -> 8 -> 9 -> null
1 -> 0 -> 3 -> 2 -> 5 -> 4 -> 7 -> 6 -> 9 -> 8 -> null

0 -> 1 -> 2 -> 3 -> 4 -> 5 -> 6 -> 7 -> 8 -> 9 -> null
2 -> 1 -> 0 -> 5 -> 4 -> 3 -> 8 -> 7 -> 6 -> 9 -> null

0 -> 1 -> 2 -> 3 -> 4 -> 5 -> 6 -> 7 -> 8 -> 9 -> null
3 -> 2 -> 1 -> 0 -> 7 -> 6 -> 5 -> 4 -> 8 -> 9 -> null

0 -> 1 -> 2 -> 3 -> 4 -> 5 -> 6 -> 7 -> 8 -> 9 -> null
4 -> 3 -> 2 -> 1 -> 0 -> 9 -> 8 -> 7 -> 6 -> 5 -> null

0 -> 1 -> 2 -> 3 -> 4 -> 5 -> 6 -> 7 -> 8 -> 9 -> null
5 -> 4 -> 3 -> 2 -> 1 -> 0 -> 6 -> 7 -> 8 -> 9 -> null

0 -> 1 -> 2 -> 3 -> 4 -> 5 -> 6 -> 7 -> 8 -> 9 -> null
6 -> 5 -> 4 -> 3 -> 2 -> 1 -> 0 -> 7 -> 8 -> 9 -> null

0 -> 1 -> 2 -> 3 -> 4 -> 5 -> 6 -> 7 -> 8 -> 9 -> null
7 -> 6 -> 5 -> 4 -> 3 -> 2 -> 1 -> 0 -> 8 -> 9 -> null

0 -> 1 -> 2 -> 3 -> 4 -> 5 -> 6 -> 7 -> 8 -> 9 -> null
8 -> 7 -> 6 -> 5 -> 4 -> 3 -> 2 -> 1 -> 0 -> 9 -> null

0 -> 1 -> 2 -> 3 -> 4 -> 5 -> 6 -> 7 -> 8 -> 9 -> null
9 -> 8 -> 7 -> 6 -> 5 -> 4 -> 3 -> 2 -> 1 -> 0 -> null
```